# NodeJS - controller - multiple queries from collections + forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, promise

Getting messy with promises and async & await. Would like to get your advice, what is the best practice for below controller case? Now it wont get user details before passing data to client.

I am doing a simply API endpoint to server side with NodeJS. Controller is making two queries to complete simply results as json object for client. Yes there is this useless run[] array but it is used when building whole event results :)

```js
exports.runresults3 = function(req, res) {

  // Route is passing ID
  console.log('id', req.params.id);

  // Test results object to fill
  const resultsParams = {
    run: [{
      runid: {},
      endtimeid: [],
      userid: [],
      endtime: [],
      username: [],
    }]
  }

  // Run objectid
  resultsParams.run[0].runid = req.params.id;

  // Get the endtimes by location/stage
  Endtime.find({stage: req.params.id})
    .then(data => {
      // First loop
      data.forEach(value => {
        resultsParams.run[0].endtimeid.push(value._id);
        resultsParams.run[0].userid.push(value.user);
        resultsParams.run[0].endtime.push(value.endtime);
      })
    })
    .then(() => {
      // Second loop to get user details for results object
      resultsParams.run[0].userid.forEach((userId, i) => {
        TempUser.findById(userId)
          .then(userdetails => {
            console.log('userdetails.name', userdetails.name);
            resultsParams.run[0].username.push(userdetails.name);
          });
      })
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.json(resultsParams);
    });
}
```

//////////// client side will get json as follows

```
{
"run": [
    {
        "runid": "5ae850d51717862590dc30d4",
        "endtimeid": [
            "5aec482d98555332145eccd3",
            "5aec48c098555332145eccd6",
            "5aec4a2c98555332145eccda",
            "5aec4ab398555332145eccdd",
            "5aec4bb998555332145ecce1",
            "5aec4e42c3bcbb196c8474fc",
            "5aec4e44c3bcbb196c8474fe",
            "5aec4e45c3bcbb196c847500"
        ],
        "userid": [
            "5aec13b098555332145eccbe",
            "5ae869c797e54a37f498c98f",
            "5aec4a1298555332145eccd7",
            "5aec4a1298555332145eccd7",
            "5aec4ba698555332145eccde",
            "5aec13a598555332145eccbc",
            "5ae869c797e54a37f498c98f",
            "5aec13b098555332145eccbe"
        ],
        "endtime": [
            24424,
            3280,
            11858,
            38874,
            5738,
            40384,
            50906,
            36717
        ],
        "username": []
    }
]
```

}

Comment: You're missing a `return` in your second `then` before `resultsParams.run[0].userid.forEach` and that `.forEach` needs to be a `.map` with a `Promise.all` so it knows to wait for all the results.

Comment: As a quick point of clarification, is it the expectation that the rows in the arrays will be in the same order across all 3 arrays ?

Would it make more sense to have an array of objects for each result instead of an array of arrays ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thank you for the reply, but did not quite work yet. Userdetails are still coming at last, so data is allready passed to client.. CodyKnapp, yes u are right, thats more cleaner

Comment: I just changed the whole results concept. Now it is doing ready results when saving them, so there is no need make complex queries when pulling results via single run id. This make me just think even it is an mvp application. :) No need for help at the moment! Thank you guys for comments!!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
exports.runresults3 = function(req, res) {

  // Route is passing ID
  console.log('id', req.params.id);

  // Test results object to fill
  const resultsParams = {
    run: [{
      runid: {},
      endtimeid: [],
      userid: [],
      endtime: [],
      username: [],
    }]
  }

  // Run objectid
  resultsParams.run[0].runid = req.params.id;

  Endtime.find({stage: req.params.id})
    .then(data => {
      return Promise.all(data.map(record => {
        TempUser.findById(record.user)
          .then(userdetails => {
            return {
              endtimeid: record._id,
              userid: record.user,
              endtime: record.endtime,
              username: userdetails.name
            };
          })
      }))
      .then(detailRecords => {
        return detailRecords.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          acc.endtimeid.push(curr.endtimeid);
          acc.userid.push(curr.userid);
          acc.endtime.push(curr.endtime);
          acc.username.push(curr.username);
          return acc;
        },resultsParams.run[0]);
      })
      .then(() => {
        res.json(resultsParams);
      });
    });
}
```

If you have a requirement to accumulate things into the "associative array" style of things in this result object, this is probably the way I would do it.

With that said, I would most likely try to return things as an array of run results - something more like the following...

```
{
  "run": [
    {
      "runid": "5ae850d51717862590dc30d4",
      "results": [
        {
          "endtimeid": "5aec482d98555332145eccd3",
          "userid": "5aec13b098555332145eccbe",
          "endtime": 24424,
          "username": "User123"
        },
        {
          "endtimeid": "5aec48c098555332145eccd6",
          "userid": "5ae869c797e54a37f498c98f",
          "endtime": 3280,
          "username": "User234"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I believe the following code should do that.

```js
exports.runresults3 = function(req, res) {

  // Route is passing ID
  console.log('id', req.params.id);

  // Test results object to fill
  const resultsParams = {
    run: [{
      runid: {},
      results: []
    }]
  }

  // Run objectid
  resultsParams.run[0].runid = req.params.id;

  Endtime.find({stage: req.params.id})
    .then(data => {
      return Promise.all(data.map(record => {
        TempUser.findById(record.user)
          .then(userdetails => {
            return {
              endtimeid: record._id,
              userid: record.user,
              endtime: record.endtime,
              username: userdetails.name
            };
          })
      }))
    })
    .then(results => resultsParams.run[0].results = reuslts)
    .then(() => res.json(resultsParams));
}
```

There could certainly be more readability refactors to be done, and the fact that the last step of populating the result doesn't use the result of the previous flow troubles me a bit - but I try to avoid side effects whenever possible, so that may just be me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited versions as adviced :) But still missing the user details, it looks like promise.all isnt waiting "TempUser.findById(record.user)" query.

1 I created a fresh event, run, 3 users and 3 results.

2 Then I set some logs along db calls

3 Then I did a get request with postman

Log from localhost look like this after Postman GET request:

$ node app
Server started on 5000
Mongodb connected
id 5aeebd8a1b5ddf1424c25194

1. Get endtimes from database

[ { created: 2018-05-06T08:32:46.359Z,
    _id: 5aeebdae1b5ddf1424c25199,
    endtime: 23204,
    user: 5aeebd751b5ddf1424c25191,
    stage: 5aeebd8a1b5ddf1424c25194,
    __v: 0 },
  { created: 2018-05-06T08:32:49.414Z,
    _id: 5aeebdb11b5ddf1424c2519b,
    endtime: 17149,
    user: 5aeebd7b1b5ddf1424c25192,
    stage: 5aeebd8a1b5ddf1424c25194,
    __v: 0 },
  { created: 2018-05-06T08:32:51.769Z,
    _id: 5aeebdb31b5ddf1424c2519d,
    endtime: 10840,
    user: 5aeebd7f1b5ddf1424c25193,
    stage: 5aeebd8a1b5ddf1424c25194,
    __v: 0 } ]

3. Set results to object

[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
This should be the last one at chain?

2. Get user details from database

{ date: 2018-05-06T08:31:49.673Z,
  _id: 5aeebd751b5ddf1424c25191,
  name: 'Firstame Lastname1',
  __v: 0 }
2. Get user details from database { date: 2018-05-06T08:31:55.562Z,
  _id: 5aeebd7b1b5ddf1424c25192,
  name: 'Firstame Lastname2',
  __v: 0 }
2. Get user details from database { date: 2018-05-06T08:31:59.906Z,
  _id: 5aeebd7f1b5ddf1424c25193,
  name: 'Firstame Lastname3',
  __v: 0 }

That is made by following code:

```js
exports.runresults3 = function(req, res) {

  // Route is passing ID
  console.log('id', req.params.id);
  
  // Test results object to fill
  const resultsParams = {
    run: [{
      runid: {},
      results: []
    }]
  }

  // Each run objectid
  resultsParams.run[0].runid = req.params.id;

  Endtime.find({stage: req.params.id})
    .then(data => {
      console.log('1. Get endtimes from database', data);
      return Promise.all(data.map(record => {
        TempUser.findById(record.user)
          .then(userdetails => {
            console.log('2. Get user details from database', userdetails);
            return {
              endtimeid: record._id,
              userid: record.user,
              endtime: record.endtime,
              username: userdetails.name
            };
          })
      }))
    })
    .then(results => { 
      console.log('3. Set results to object', results);
      console.log('This should be the last one at chain?');
      
      resultsParams.run[0].results = results;
    })
    .then(() => res.json(resultsParams));
}
```